# tabgroupactivity in android with BaseAdapter

Tags: android, tabs, parent, baseadapter, android-adapter

I have to develop an one android application.

Here i  have using tabgroup activity.

i have using following code on my adapter file:

```
   convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                 ArrayList<SubCategory> beanSubCat = categoriesList.getmSubCategories();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(),SubCategoryDetails.class);
                 TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
                intent.putExtra("SubCategoryDetails", beanSubCat);
                intent.putExtra("title", categoriesList.getmCategoryName());
    parentActivity.startChildActivity("SubCategoryDetails",intent);
```

i am getting following error :

**The method getParent() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}**

How can i resolve these error .. please give me solution for these ???

**EDIT:**

I have using adapter class here.(For eg:public class CategoriesAdapter extends BaseAdapter)how can i get the getparent() in Adapter class ??? please give me solution ???

**EDIT:**

I have using following code:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(activity,SubCategoryDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("SubCategoryDetails", beanSubCat);
                intent.putExtra("title", categoriesList.getmCategoryName());
                activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Now am activity is going to next activity well.

But i have using tabgroupactivity means am getting above error ???
please give me any ideas ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
Activity activity;
Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getParent(),SubCategoryDetails.class);
```

Comment: i didn't use activity.here i have using BaseAdapter.public class CategoriesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Comment: k, then use getActivity().getParent()

Comment: am getting below error:The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: Ok, try getContext() istead of getparent()

Comment: like, Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),SubCategoryDetails.class);

Comment: no yar.am getting following error:The method getContext() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: i got it...declared  globally private Activity activity;afterthat add the below line Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getParent(),SubCategoryDetails.class);...now i get the exact answer.thanks for gave me a idea.please edit these on ur answer